# Datagridview image column moves on update

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

On my form i got datagridview which is populating by some data. There is also a combobx on this form and when selection change has happend then based on selected value - datagridview datasource is set to be nothing and then filled up again. Everything was working well until i decided to add additional datagridview image column which i placed on the end of grid and to show images based on text from some previous column text data. Unfortunetly i have problem with displaying images itself (red marks) and biggest problem is when i change combobox selection my additional datagrid image column is moving 1 position to left everytime combo is changed. I've spent whole day looking for issue but can't find any answer on that. I thought maybe that's because grid datasource is not being cleaned (nothing) but it is. Can you please help me out what could be a problem here? Below find my code and screenshoots of problem. Hope you help me to fix it as i am really stackoverflowed.

**My Form Load event - that's where i load combobox:**

```
 Private Sub FrmTransportView_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        RemoveHandler CboProjects.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf CboProjects_SelectedIndexChanged
        Try
            mydb.OpenConn()
            If mydb.conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                Form.InitCombo(CboProjects, "SELECT * from tbProjekt", mydb.conn, "Nazwa", "Id")
                mydb.CloseConn()
                'ChangeControlsLanguage()
                Trans = New Transport
                Trans.ProjectId = CboProjects.SelectedValue
                RefreshGridAfterProjectIdChanged()
                AddHandler CboProjects.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf CboProjects_SelectedIndexChanged
End Try
    End Sub
```

**PopulateGrid method:**

```
Public Sub PopulateGrid()
        Try
            If IsNothing(Trans.ListByProjectId_checkifanyrows()) Then
  Me.BeginInvoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf Me.Close))
Else
 Else
                dgvTransport.DataSource = Nothing   'Clean datagrid before new data

                dgvTransport.Refresh()
                dgvTransport.DataSource = Trans.ListByProjectId()
                AlignGrid()
                PlaceImages()
            End If
  End Try
    End Sub
```

**Align method** - placed within PopulateGrid method as you see when  dgvTransport as set to nohing and then its detasource set to new data: Trans.ListByProjectId() now i am aligning it - hiding some columns etc... As you can see also i am adding this new image column... :

```
 Private Sub AlignGrid()
        Try
            dgvTransport.Columns(0).Visible = False         'Project id
            dgvTransport.Columns(1).Visible = False         'Id
            dgvTransport.Columns(2).Visible = True          'Lp                                                      
            dgvTransport.Columns(3).Visible = True          'Status                                                  
            dgvTransport.Columns(4).Visible = True          'Dataprzyjazdu                                           
            dgvTransport.Columns(5).Visible = True          'DataRozpoczeciaZaladunku                                

          dgvTransport.Columns(6).Visible = True          'DataOdjazdu                                             
            dgvTransport.Columns(7).Visible = True          'TypTransportu                                                   dgvTransport.Columns(8).Visible = False          'TypKontenera  (reprezentacja liczbowa z tabeli tbTransport)    
            dgvTransport.Columns(9).Visible = True          'NumerKontenera                                          
            dgvTransport.Columns(10).Visible = True         'NumerCiezarowki                                         
            dgvTransport.Columns(11).Visible = True         'Plomba   
            dgvTransport.Columns(12).Visible = False        'Kierowca
            dgvTransport.Columns(13).Visible = False         'Opis
            dgvTransport.Columns(14).Visible = False        'Nazwa (nazwa projektu)
            dgvTransport.Columns(15).Visible = True        'TypKontenera (reprezentacja za pomoca nazwy ze zlaczenia INNER JOIN))

            Dim img As DataGridViewImageColumn = New DataGridViewImageColumn()
            img.HeaderText = "Status2"
            img.Name = "Status2"
            dgvTransport.Columns.Insert(16, img)

            'potrzebny aby zadzialalo: DgvMach.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Gold 
            dgvTransport.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = False

            'headers look
            With dgvTransport.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle
                'The way to do this is to set the EnableHeadersVisualStyles flag for the data grid view to False, and set the background colour via the ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor property. For example, to set the background colour to blue, use the following (or set in the designer if you prefer):
                'If you do not set the EnableHeadersVisualStyles flag to False, then the changes you make to the style of the header will not take effect, as the grid will use the style from the current users default theme. The MSDN documentation for this property is here.
                .BackColor = Color.White

                .ForeColor = Color.Black
                .Font = New Font("Ariel", 10, FontStyle.Regular)
                .Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
            End With

            dgvTransport.AllowUserToAddRows = False
            dgvTransport.[ReadOnly] = True
            dgvTransport.MultiSelect = False
            dgvTransport.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect        'zaznacza caly wiersz po kliknieciu


            dgvTransport.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill      'WAZNE!!!: RESIZUJE CALY CONTENT GRIDA NIE ZOSSTAWIAJAC CIEMNEGO TLA !!!
            dgvTransport.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells

            With dgvTransport.DefaultCellStyle
                .BackColor = Color.White
                .ForeColor = Color.Black
                .Font = New Font("Ariel", 9, FontStyle.Regular)
                .Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
            End With
'This will disable row autosizing and manual row resizing. To set the row height you can use the Height and MinimumHeight properties of the RowTemplate.
            dgvTransport.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.None
            dgvTransport.AllowUserToResizeRows = False
    End Sub
```

**FrmTransportView_Shown event:**

```
Private Sub FrmTransportView_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Shown
        AddHandler dgvTransport.SelectionChanged, AddressOf dgvTransport_SelectionChanged
    End Sub
```

**RefreshGridAfterProjectIdChanged**

```
Public Sub RefreshGridAfterProjectIdChanged()
        Trans.ProjectId = CboProjects.SelectedValue
        PopulateGrid()
    End Sub
```

**CboProjects_SelectedIndexChanged**

```
Private Sub CboProjects_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CboProjects.SelectedIndexChanged
        RefreshGridAfterProjectIdChanged()
    End Sub
```

**PlaceImages**

```
 Private Sub PlaceImages()
            For i As Integer = 0 To dgvTransport.Rows.Count - 1
                Dim sHeader As String = dgvTransport.Columns(16).Name

                If sHeader = "Status2" Then
                    Dim LINK = dgvTransport.Rows(i).Cells(8).Value

                    If LINK.ToString.Contains("1") Then
                        Dim Img As New DataGridViewImageCell
                        Img.Value = My.Resources._1
                        dgvTransport.Rows(i).Cells(16).Value = Img.Value
                    End If
                    If LINK.ToString.Contains("2") Then
                        Dim Img As New DataGridViewImageCell
                        Img.Value = My.Resources._2
                        dgvTransport.Rows(i).Cells(16).Value = Img.Value
                    End If
                    If LINK.ToString.Contains("3") Then
                        Dim Img As New DataGridViewImageCell
                        Img.Value = My.Resources._3
                        dgvTransport.Rows(i).Cells(16).Value = Img.Value
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        End Sub
```

**That's how it looks for first form load:** (strange thing is column index of image column (Status2) is 0 - should be 16 as i placed index for that column to 16 in Align method.. As you see also not images are showing up...

[image]

**Now when i am going to change selection in combobox:**

of course as you can note from code this method handler is called: CboProjects_SelectedIndexChanged

so then again grid datasource will be set to Nothing, populate again, then align gird..

and that's what is shown after: (see indexes - also some image show up and column "Status2" was moved to left..)

[image]

**3rd combobox change etc...**

[image]

Hope to find someone here to help me out as i really have no idea how to fix that. Hope everything is clear.

Comment: is there anyone who could help  here?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this is coming a little late. Just a suggestion - I didn't experiment with it. Try to insert the DataGridImageColumn first before editing the visibility of the other columns.

Not too related, but in your `AlignGrid` sub, the static properties like ".BackColor" can be set on design just to reduce code.

Let us know your observations.

Thanks